# How to get the Description to the product quick view page?

Tags: magento2

I have to display description on product list view page, But I want to display description to click quick view popup page.

[image]

[image]

plz, check image?

Comment: provide more info , which theme and plugins you are using for this

Comment: theme -http://alothemes.com/demo2/digitalstore/index.php/

Comment: i dont know which plugin i was use

Comment: <?php echo $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getDescription(), 'description') ?>

try like this

Comment: which files i have include this code ...any idea

Comment: this theme has option to add short description in quick view, find out in admin ..

Comment: not any properties to set quickview in admin panel in theme

Answer (score 0):

To get product description in the quickview pop-up do the following:

1. Create a new template file (new .phtml file) and place it in your theme directory Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view
2. In your template file, say quickview-descr.phtml place this code:

   ```
    <?php
     // @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
     /**
     * Product description template
     *
     * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description
     * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes
     */
     ?>
     <p class="just"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($block->getProduct(), $block->getProduct()->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?></p>
   ```

*You can use

```
->getDescription(), 'description'
```

For the full product description.

3. Then, you need to locate your theme's XML layout file for the quick view feature.
   Say, it may be located in your parent theme (if you're using a child theme) Magento_Catalog/layout or it may be located in something like Customtheme_Quickview/layout

The layout name will be similar to: quickview_product_view.xml

In the layout file, find

```
 <container name="product.info.main"> or <container name="product.info.details">
```

and locate the position within the quick view page layout where you want to place the product description.

Say, you may want to place it under the product title container

```
 <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title" name="page.main.title" template="html/title.phtml"/>
```

4. Call your template file from the quick view layout at the desired location:

   ```
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.details" template="product/view/quickview-descr.phtml" after="page.main.title" />
   ```

Save. Clear cache

php bin/magento cache:flush